# Oracle: Blob column throws inconsistent datatypes

Tags: database, oracle, blob, distinct

I have three oracle environments, and a query that runs successfully in two environments but throws `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB`  in the third environment.

The query

```
select
        distinct mytable.ID as ID1_130_,
        mytable.CODE as CODE2_130_,
        mytable.MY_LOGO as PRIMARY_8_130_,
    from
        MY_TABLE mytable;
```

The MY_LOGO column is BLOB

Can anyone explain why the query throw the exception only on the third Database or what I should check?

Comment: You can't use a BLOB column together with `DISTINCT`

Comment: but it works fine into other environments?

Comment: Then the column isn't a BLOB in the other environments

Comment: no the column is blob into all the environments and it was working in the third environment before then  suddenly it stop working. somehow like the scenario of this post
https://magnusjohanssontuning.wordpress.com/2018/11/01/ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-got-blob/

Comment: Apparently, you found the answer in Magnus' blog. The best way would be if you post an answer so the other users can share it. Ideally, you would verify Magnus suspicion by finding out the result of the query in your three environments: 
`SELECT constraint_type, status, validated FROM alL_constraints WHERE table_name='MYTABLE';` and include it in your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: You need to rebuild the primary key in the third environment.

The error message is misleading (as so often with Oracle), it should rather be *'DISTINCT does not work with BLOBs'*.

Your hint with Magnus Johansson was correct, it's the status of the primary key. Here is a minimal example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY, b BLOB);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, EMPTY_BLOB());
```

`SELECT DISTINCT` works, as long as the primary key is selected, too. Possibly with the logic that if the primary key is involved, the rest of the columns, including the BLOB, are guaranteed to be distinct, too:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, b FROM t;
1 (BLOB)

SELECT DISTINCT b FROM t;
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB
```

This works only as long as the supporting index is healty. If you move (or restructure) the table, so that the index becomes unusable, you get your omnious error message:

```
ALTER TABLE t MOVE;
SELECT status from USER_INDEXES WHERE index_name='PK';
UNUSABLE

SELECT DISTINCT id, b FROM t;
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB
```

Once you repair the index, it works again:

```
ALTER INDEX pk REBUILD;
SELECT status from USER_INDEXES WHERE index_name='PK';
VALID

SELECT DISTINCT id, b FROM t;
1 (BLOB)
```

Weird!